# Присваивание в переменную результат работы mysql2

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

День добрый. Второй день бьюсь головой не знаю как вернуть значение.

Суть такая: Делаю форму авторизации. При нажатии на кнопку войти собираются значения из полей, шифруются в MD5 и отправляются на сервер NODE.JS

```js
Login(){
        let secure = md5(this.state.login + this.state.password);
        console.log(secure);
        axios.post(`${cfg.server.ip}/login`, {
            'hash': secure
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           alert(error);
        });
    }
```

Сервер же в свою очередь обрабатывает полученный хеш, делает запрос к БД MySQL, и если полученный хеш имеется в БД(т.е. пользователь существует), возвращает `true`, если пароль не верный(соответственно хеш тоже) возвращает `false` (в дальнейшем будет заменено на токен)

```js
fastify.post('/login', (req) => {   
  const hash = req.body.hash;
  const query =`SELECT COUNT(*) AS \'cnt\' FROM admin where login = \'${hash}\'`;
  connection.query(query, (error, result) => {
    if(error) console.log(error);
    if(result[0].cnt === 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Как вернуть пользователю `true` или `false`?

Comment: Во-первых, MD5 это не шифрование. Во-вторых, MD5 принципиально непригоден для скрытия паролей, он создавался не для этого. В-третьих, у вас SQL-инъекция

Comment: В-четвёртых, дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Ну а применительно к mysql2 и fastify, судя по их документациям ([mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper), [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Getting-Started/)), они оба вполне поддерживают async/await, так что никаких проблем с возвратом откуда угодно куда угодно быть не должно, если вы перепишете всё на async/await

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'127.0.0.1',port: 3306, user: 'root', database: 'phantom'});
const [rows] = await connection.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `cnt` FROM `admin` where `login` = ?', [hash]);
```

из rows[0].cnt уже получаю результат